# Syntax Error GraphQL Expected Name, found String

Tags: node.js, graphql, syntax-error, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to implement mutations in GraphQL. I am using GraphQL Play Ground Ui for query.

Here is my mutation :

```
mutation{
  createProduct (data :{
     product: "abc", 
     product_status : {
      "1" : {
      order : "done"    
}

}
```

Here is my TypeDef

```
type Product { 
product : String,
product_status : JSON
}
```

But I am getting error in product_status **excepted Name but found String** as object contains **1** as string. How can i resolve this. I need to store this type of object in My database.Can someone help me to this.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3eT6.png)

Comment: `product_status` is not of type `JSON`. As a matter of fact, there's no such type in `GraphQL` unless you create a custom one. `product_status` in your first code snippet looks like an object so you need to create a custom type for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL supports strict data typing. So basically you can't have a string as a property key because that would mean it wouldn't know what to deserialize into. Also I'm not sure if JSON is a data type. I know strings and types but not JSON. You coudld have a object like:

```
type Product { 
    product : String,
    product_status : ProductStatus
}

type ProductStatus {
    id: ID,
    order: String,
}
```

This is how you could design it.